# NSNumber, Setting and Retrieving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumber

I'm messing around with NSNumber for an iPhone app, and seeing what I can do with it.  For most of my variables, I simple store them as "int" or "float" or whatnot.  However, when I have to pass an object (Such as in a Dictionary) then I need them as an Object.  I use NSNUmber.  This is how I initialize the object.

```
NSNumber *testNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:varMoney];
```

Where "varMoney" is an int I have declared earlier in the program.  However, I have absolutely no idea how to get that number back...

for example:

```
varMoney2 = [NSNumber retrieve the variable...];
```

How do I get the value back from the object and set it to a regular "int" again?

Thanks!

(Out of curiosity, is there a way to store "int" directly in an Objective-C dictionary without putting it in an NSNumber first?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want -intValue, or one of its friends (-floatValue, -doubleValue, etc.). From the docs:

> intValue Returns the receiver’s value
>   as an int.
>
> `- (int)intValue`
>
> Return Value The receiver’s value as
>   an int, converting it as necessary.

The code would be:

```
int varMoney2 = [testNum intValue];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSNumber *testNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:varMoney];
/* Then later... */
int newVarMoney = [testNum intValue];
```